# Игнорировать определенные символы в preg_replace

Tags: php

Я нашел в интернете очень удобную [штуку](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php#89364), но там сказано что такие символы как `",.?\"` нельзя вводить так как они есть символами-атрибутами. Как прописать код так что бы он игнорировал(не удалял) все буквы алфавита, цифры и символы `",./?!"` ?

Что есть:

```
$name = preg_replace("/[^а-яa-zA-ZА-Я0-9\s]+/u","",$string);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно экранировать /, а остальные символы в квадратных скобках можете перечислять без экрана. Вот так, например:

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^\d\s\/.,!?a-zа-яё]/iu','', $string);
```

Comment: А что значит `\d`? Я вижу что нецифровой символ, но что это?

Comment: `\d` - это эквивалент `0-9`

Answer (score 1):

Требуется экранировать данные символы

```
 preg_replace("/[^а-яa-zA-ZА-Я0-9\,\.\/\?\!\s]+/u","",$string);
```

[Специальные символы](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php#89364)